# PHP partial uploads image

Tags: php, upload

So, this is the problem: I upload a file, it's uploaded successfully. But the image it's partially uploaded: the first 700kb get uploaded, while the rest of the image is just white or grey. 
This is an example: 
[image]

The script is working correctly itself, I tried on different hostings but it does this "trick" on a specific hosting only. I think it's somethinga bout server configuration. It uses cpanel. My php options are set  to have maximum memory limit, upload limit and post_size. 
This is the script:

```
$filename           = basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $error                  = false;

    $absolutedir            = dirname(__FILE__);
    $dir                    = '/tmp/';
    $serverdir              = $absolutedir.$dir;

    $tmp                    = explode(',',$_POST['file']);
    $file                   = base64_decode($tmp[1]);

    $extension              = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_POST['filename'])));
    $filename               = $_POST['name'].'.'.$extension;
    //$filename             = $file.'.'.substr(sha1(time()),0,6).'.'.$extension;

    file_put_contents($serverdir.$filename, $file);

    /*$handle                   = fopen($serverdir.$filename,'w');
    fwrite($handle, $file);
    fclose($handle);*/

    $response = array(
            "result"        => true,
            "url"           => $dir.$filename.'?'.time(), //added the time to force update when editting multiple times
            "filename"      => $filename
    );

    echo json_encode($response);
    //echo json_encode(array('result'=>true));

} else {
    $filename           = basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $file_url           = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp/'.$filename;
    header('Content-Type:               application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  Binary");
    header("Content-disposition:        attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");
    readfile($file_url); 
    exit();
}
```

Both `file_put_contents` and `fwrite` have the same behaviour.

Let's recap: image < 700kb = fully uploaded. image > 700kb, first 700kb uploaded, the rest of the image is grey or white. I'm very confused.

HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="html5fileupload.form.php" method="POST" class="contactForm validateIt" data-email-subject="Request Form" data-show-errors="true" >
   <div class="html5fileupload demo_basic" data-url="html5fileupload.php" data-max-filesize="12288000" data-multiple="true"  data-autostart="true" style="width: 100%;">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" multiple> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess you have checked the php.ini...

Comment: As I wrote in the post, yes. Upload_max_filesize: 64MB. Post_max_size: 128MB, Memory_limit: 256MB

Comment: Can you show your form's HTML code? don't post it in the comments

Comment: updated with HTML form. As I said it's working fine everywhere except this particular hosting (which is owned by a customer of mine, so I can't change it).

Comment: why aren't you using `move_uploaded_file` to upload the images ? are you open to an answer using `move_uploaded_file` ?

Comment: even that method not working.